# Textos quebrados

Tags: html, css

Tenho um imageButton que representa arquivos, e um label nele:

```
<div class="block">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="idDirectorio" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("guid") %>' />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="isFolder" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("isFolder") %>' />

    <asp:ImageButton ID="btSend" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imgPath") %>' OnClick="btSend_Click" />

    <div class="bottom">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="check" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="check_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("xInfo") %>' />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Atual:

```
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80x;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 1px;
}

.block .bottom {
    font-size:small;
    height: 27px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;  
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.block .bottom input {
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

.block .bottom spam,
.block .bottom label {
    max-width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Resultado feio:
    [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Resumindo os nomes passam para o outro, e não quebram a linha, e arquivos que vem do windows com o traço - , quebra tambem.
Como ajeitar isso?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, me parece um problema com `white-space`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro corrige `spam` com "m" para `span` com "n". Adicione a propriedade `word-wrap` com valor `break-word`:

```
.block .bottom span,
.block .bottom label {
    max-width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

Adicione também `vertical-align` para alinhar os itens:

```
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80x;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Corrigiu os problemas dos arquivos que vinha com traço, porem continua passando para o outro, ainda nao quebra para baixo.

Comment: melhorou muito, mas arquivos com nome grande, ainda esta passando...

Comment: se souber o que pode ser edita ai.

Comment: Vc consegue reproduzir isso num snippet? Achei que o word-wrap iria resolver

Comment: reproduzir como?

Comment: Repetir esse problema no http://jsfiddle.net por exemplo, vai ficar mais fácil de outra pessoa resolver

Comment: é pq estou usando componentes nativos .net, nao é html puro.Postei a imagem de como ainda esta.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e3acv67r/

Comment: Achei o erro: vc colocou "spam" com "m" ao invés de "n" :D

Comment: Perfeito, vlw... Se um texto for muito grande, pra aparecer os 3 pontinhos tem que usar js?

Comment: Dá pra usar [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)